# Convergence rate of $\alpha_n = \ln(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, rate-of-convergence

Expanding $\ln(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n})$ into its Maclaurin series we get:

$\ln(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{(-1)^2n}{2!n} + \frac{(-1)^3n}{3!n} + \cdots + R$ for some remainder R.

Letting $\beta_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ 
and taking $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|\alpha_n - 0|}{|\beta_n|}$ we get $1.$

But I'm sure the rate of convergence is supposed to be $\frac{1}{n}$ not $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Are they the same? If so, how can I show it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of rate of convergence uses absolute values... and is a number, not a sequence. A sequence $x_n \to a$ has rate of convergence $\beta$ if
$$
\lim \frac{|x_{n+1}-a|}{|x_n-a|^{\beta}} = M
$$
for some constant $M>0$. In your case, you must search for a number $\beta$ such that the limit

$$
\lim \frac{\left|\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)\right|}{\left|\ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\right)\right|^{\beta}}
$$

is a positive number.  In fact, if you take $\beta=1$, the above limit is $1$, showing that the sequence converges linearly to zero.

Comment: For $|x|<1$ let $F(x)=\int_1^{1+x}f(t)dt$   where $f(t)=1/t$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $1=f(1)=F'(1)=$ $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {F(1+x)-F(1)}{(1+x)-1}=$ $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {F(1+x)}{x}=$ $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\ln(1+x)}{x}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for the input this is a nice way of showing that the limit is in fact 1,

Comment: Thanks for this! Technically, this is a different characterization of convergence called "order of convergence." Not sure if textbooks differ in this distinction. I was asking about "rate of convergence." But this answer was helpful to solidify the former concept for me.

Answer (score 0):

$ln(1+x)=x-\frac {x^{2}} 2+o(x^{2})$ so $\alpha_n =\frac {(-1)^{n}} n -\frac  1 {2n^2} +o(n^{-2})$.  This means $\alpha_n - \frac {(-1)^{n}} n$ tends to $0$ at the rate of $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Comment: The limit is indeed $0$, but I was asking about the rate of its convergence to $0$.